# iOS AppStore: How can I add keywords in Arabic to make it searchable using Arabic words?

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, app-store, itunes

My iOS application is available in both English and Arabic Language. The language selection is within the application. While uploading the application I mentioned only English language as my localization option. Also added few arabic keywords in keywords area (e.g. EngKeyWord1, EngKeyWord2, ArabicKeyWord1). But the app is not searchable using Arabic keywords.

Am I doing things right? Is there a different way of doing this?

[Arabic as a language option is not available in iTunes Metadata section. But there are other apps which are searchable using Arabic keywords!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iTunes Connect only allows you to add metadata for the languages in which your application itself is localized. Since you did not localize the app in the normal way (i.e. you implemented an in-app language selector instead of relying on the standard localization method which depends on the iOS language setting), maybe you did not explicitly add Arabic to your application in XCode?

You can do this in XCode by selecting your project, opening the Info tab and using the "+" button under Localizations and choosing Arabic. Then you'll have to upload the binary before iTunes Connect allows you to enter Arabic metadata.

**Edit:** This is out of date. iTunes Connect now lets you add metadata for languages beyond those your application bundle is localized into.